# Sort a text string column of a pandas dataframe by the first letter in the string

Tags: pandas, sorting, dataframe, text

I have a pandas df that I need to sort by a column variable that is a text string. I have tried three approaches. The first two are similar. The last approach sorts, but it also produces a mystery column.

Here's the small test data set:

```
raw_corpus  #test data


unique_ID   count   trigger_channel_cat
0   11530   1   Photo and Video
1   17176   1   Environment Control and Monitoring
2   6984    1   Security and Monitoring Systems
3   15696   1   Photo and Video
4   16103   3   Finance and Payments
5   18534   5   News and Information
6   11677   331 Social Networks
7   702 1   Contacts
8   7251    1   Business Tools
9   10609   1   Photo and Video
10  1703    2   Blogging
11  20567   1   Social Networks
12  8357    1   Social Networks
13  4313    1   Fitness and Wearables
14  8552    1   Contacts
15  7634    1   News and Information
16  13698   1   Social Networks
17  13940   4   Business Tools
18  19784   3   Location
19  3561    1   Task Management and To-Dos
```

Using value_counts doesn't work:

```
raw_corpus_sorted=raw_corpus['trigger_channel_cat'].value_counts().index.tolist()
raw_corpus_sorted

['Social Networks',
 'Photo and Video',
 'Business Tools',
 'Contacts',
 'News and Information',
 'Fitness and Wearables',
 'Location',
 'Security and Monitoring Systems',
 'Task Management and To-Dos',
 'Environment Control and Monitoring',
 'Blogging',
 'Finance and Payments']
```

Try again with a different call to value_counts gives the correct number of instances per category, but does not sort the categories:

```
raw_corpus_sorted=raw_corpus['trigger_channel_cat'].value_counts(sort=True) 
raw_corpus_sorted

Social Networks                       4
Photo and Video                       3
Business Tools                        2
Contacts                              2
News and Information                  2
Fitness and Wearables                 1
Location                              1
Security and Monitoring Systems       1
Task Management and To-Dos            1
Environment Control and Monitoring    1
Blogging                              1
Finance and Payments                  1
Name: trigger_channel_cat, dtype: int64
```

Using sort_values() does sort! But what is the first column of ints???

```
#this one works - but what is that first column?
raw_corpus_sorted=raw_corpus['trigger_channel_cat'].sort_values()
raw_corpus_sorted

10                              Blogging
17                        Business Tools
8                         Business Tools
14                              Contacts
7                               Contacts
1     Environment Control and Monitoring
4                   Finance and Payments
13                 Fitness and Wearables
18                              Location
15                  News and Information
5                   News and Information
0                        Photo and Video
9                        Photo and Video
3                        Photo and Video
2        Security and Monitoring Systems
11                       Social Networks
6                        Social Networks
16                       Social Networks
12                       Social Networks
19            Task Management and To-Dos
Name: trigger_channel_cat, dtype: object
```

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: adding () fixes the last example! still no clue why first don't work. will update with an MCVE in a moment...

Comment: @StephenRauch  MCVE added

Answer (score 2):

You need add () and pass the target column to sort at the end when you call `sort_values`

```
raw_corpus_sorted=raw_corpus.sort_values('trigger_channel_clean')
```

Since you add the data

```
df.sort_values(' trigger_channel_cat')
Out[1086]: 
    unique_ID  count      trigger_channel_cat
10       1703      2                 Blogging
17      13940      4           Business Tools
8        7251      1           Business Tools
14       8552      1                 Contacts
1       17176      1  Environment Control and
4       16103      3     Finance and Payments
13       4313      1    Fitness and Wearables
18      19784      3                 Location
15       7634      1     News and Information
5       18534      5     News and Information
0       11530      1          Photo and Video
9       10609      1          Photo and Video
3       15696      1          Photo and Video
2        6984      1  Security and Monitoring
12       8357      1          Social Networks
6       11677    331          Social Networks
16      13698      1          Social Networks
11      20567      1          Social Networks
19       3561      1  Task Management and To-
7         702      1                     acts
```

For `value_counts` , you can `sort_index`

```
df['trigger_channel_cat'].value_counts(sort=True).sort_index()
Out[1088]: 
Blogging                   1
Business Tools             2
Contacts                   1
Environment Control and    1
Finance and Payments       1
Fitness and Wearables      1
Location                   1
News and Information       2
Photo and Video            3
Security and Monitoring    1
Social Networks            4
Task Management and To-    1
acts                       1
Name:  trigger_channel_cat, dtype: int64
```